# Accepting request in Jersey webservice

Tags: java, xml, json, jersey

Let us assume ,for my Jersey project somebody is trying to send a request in the form of a string(String is obtained by converting some json details like username and password).Is my java code capable to accept it?

```
@Path("/customers")
public class Authentication {
    @POST
    @Path("/get")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getRequestUrl(String JSON_DATA) {

        System.out.println("inside Authentication");

//       String output = s.toString();

         return Response.status(201).entity(JSON_DATA).build();
    }
```

If not how to accept a request for further processing.Can anybody gives its explanation(Especially about get and post method).Advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you should test it.

This is a working example from my testproject:

```
    @POST
@Path("/post2")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response addPerson(MultivaluedMap<String, String> map) {
    // Dummy data
    fillList();
    Person person = new Person("Sample", 44);

    // Get persons name and age from input fields
    int age = Integer.parseInt(map.getFirst("age"));
    String name = map.getFirst("name");

    person = new Person(name, age);
    lijst.add(person);
    return Response.ok(person.toString()).build();
}
```

The service was online and I made an Android project to add a person to this list. It worked perfect :-)